# Bluetooth low energy application Metro style

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to develop a windows 8 metro app (C# and XAML) which support the bluetooth low energy(BLE) feature. I found a sample Windows Phone app for this.I tried to convert to Windows 8 app, but some features are not supporting in Windows 8 like **Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice** . Is there any Windows 8 application for BLE? Please help me.

Please see the link: Windows phone app for BLE
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bluetooth-LE-Explorer-91669105